# PHP - Search results not paginating

Tags: php, mysql, search, pagination

I'm trying to get search results to paginate if there are greater than 10 items found in the database. For some reason, even though the code recognises there are more than 10 items and creates links for subsequent pages, all search results are listed on the first page only. Anyone able to help please? Code is below:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $terms_count; $i++)
{
    $search_terms_array[$i] = trim($search_terms_array[$i]);
    ${"query".$i} = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT prod_id, prod_tags FROM table WHERE prod_tags LIKE '%" . $search_terms_array[$i] . "%'");
    if(${"query".$i}->num_rows < 1)
    {
        $zerocount++;
    }
    else
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = ${"query".$i}->fetch_array())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $search_id_results[] = $row['prod_id'];
        }
    }
}
if($zerocount == $terms_count)
{
    echo $this->err_handle->fetch_error_text("search_terms_0_results");
    return;
}
else
{
    $search_results = array_values(array_unique($search_id_results));
    $search_results_count = count($search_results);
    $search_page_count = ceil($search_results_count / 10);
    $search_page_first_result = ($search_page - 1) * 10;
    echo '<p>Go to page: ';
    for($i = 1; $i <= $search_page_count; $i++)
    {
        if($i == $search_page)
        {
            echo "&nbsp;<strong>" . $i . "</strong>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo '&nbsp;<a href="index.php?section=products&amp;action=search&amp;page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
    }
    echo '</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>';
    for($i = 0; $i < $search_results_count; $i++)
    {
        $query = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE prod_id='" . $search_results[$i] . "' LIMIT " . $search_page_first_result . ", 10");
        while($row = $query->fetch_array())
        {
        echo "<h4><a href=\"index.php?section=products&amp;subsection=" . $row['prod_category'] . "&amp;prodid=" . $row['prod_id'] . "\">" . $row['prod_name'] . "</h4></a><p><img src=\"includes/images/product_images/" . $row['prod_category'] . "/" . $row['prod_pic_filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" width=\"150\" height=\"200\" /></p><p>Price: £" . $row['prod_price'] . "</p><p>" . $row['prod_code'] . "</p><input type=\"number\" name=\"prod_qty\" maxlength=\"2\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"add_to_basket\" value=\"Add To Basket\" /></form></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";
        }
    }
    echo '<p>Go to page: ';
    for($i = 1; $i <= $search_page_count; $i++)
    {
        if($i == $search_page)
        {
            echo "&nbsp;<strong>" . $i . "</strong>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo '&nbsp;<a href="index.php?section=products&amp;action=search&amp;page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
    }
    echo '</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>';
}
```

Comment: I think the same query that powers your search should power your pagination request so they get the same count. This way everything is in sync. Don't you think?

Comment: @mueyiwa-moses-ikomi Yeah that's something else I've looked at, however if I do `${"query".$i} = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT prod_id, prod_tags FROM table WHERE prod_tags LIKE '%" . $search_terms_array[$i] . "%' LIMIT " . $search_page_first_result . ", 10");` then only the first 10 results get returned, it won't paginate.

Comment: for pagination, you should get the count first and match that against your limit. if your query returns a count greater than your limit, then there's content to be paginated. Do you understand now? besides, does your script work with regular pagination?

Comment: Oki doki I understand now, I shall adjust the code a little later on and see what I can come up with and shall let you know. 
On the site I have a products section where you can view a single category of products that paginates fine with similar code. Thanks for the help so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution to this problem and the full function is now as follows:

```
public function product_search($search_terms, $search_page, $search_flag_check)
{
    if($search_flag_check == "invalid")
    {
        echo $this->err_handle->fetch_error_text("invalid_ns_term");
        return;
    }
    if($search_terms == "")
    {
        echo $this->err_handle->fetch_error_text("no_search_string");
        return;
    }
    $search_terms = htmlspecialchars($search_terms);
    $search_terms = $this->mysqli_link->real_escape_string(filter_var($search_terms, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES));
    $search_terms_array = explode(" ", $search_terms);
    $terms_count = count($search_terms_array);
    $zerocount = 0;
    $search_id_results = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $terms_count; $i++)
    {
        $search_terms_array[$i] = trim($search_terms_array[$i]);
        ${"query".$i} = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT prod_id, prod_tags FROM table WHERE prod_tags LIKE '%" . $search_terms_array[$i] . "%'");
        if(${"query".$i}->num_rows < 1)
        {
            $zerocount++;
        }
        else
        {
            $rows = array();
            while($row = ${"query".$i}->fetch_array())
            {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
            foreach($rows as $row)
            {
                $search_id_results[] = $row['prod_id'];
            }
        }
    }
    if($zerocount == $terms_count)
    {
        echo $this->err_handle->fetch_error_text("search_terms_0_results");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $search_results = array_values(array_unique($search_id_results));
        $search_results_count = count($search_results);
        $search_page_count = ceil($search_results_count / 10);
        $search_page_first_result = ($search_page - 1) * 10;
        $search_page_results_limit = 10;
        if($search_page_first_result < 1)
        {
            $search_page_first_result = 1;
        }
        echo '<p>Go to page: ';
        for($i = 1; $i <= $search_page_count; $i++)
        {
            if($i == $search_page)
            {
                echo "&nbsp;<strong>" . $i . "</strong>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo '&nbsp;<a href="index.php?section=products&amp;action=search&amp;page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        }
        echo '</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>';
        $search_page_upper_limit = $search_page_first_result + 9;
        if(array_key_exists($search_page_upper_limit, $search_results))
        {
            $search_results_limit = $search_page_first_result + $search_page_results_limit;
        }
        else
        {
            end($search_results);
            $search_results_limit = key($search_results);
            reset($search_results);
        }
        for($i = $search_page_first_result; $i <= $search_results_limit; $i++)
        {
            $query2 = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE prod_id='" . $search_results[$i] . "'");
            $row = $query2->fetch_array();

            echo "<h4><a href=\"index.php?section=products&amp;subsection=" . $row['prod_category'] . "&amp;prodid=" . $row['prod_id'] . "\">" . $row['prod_name'] . "</h4></a><p><img src=\"includes/images/product_images/" . $row['prod_category'] . "/" . $row['prod_pic_filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" width=\"150\" height=\"200\" /></p><p>Price: £" . $row['prod_price'] . "</p><p>" . $row['prod_code'] . "</p><input type=\"number\" name=\"prod_qty\" maxlength=\"2\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"add_to_basket\" value=\"Add To Basket\" /></form></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";

        }
        echo '<p>Go to page: ';
        for($i = 1; $i <= $search_page_count; $i++)
        {
            if($i == $search_page)
            {
                echo "&nbsp;<strong>" . $i . "</strong>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo '&nbsp;<a href="index.php?section=products&amp;action=search&amp;page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        }
        echo '</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>';
    }
}
```

It took a bit of thinking and I was about to give up, but then I thought about using the array keys to calculate the limits for each search page and after a bit of googling on relevant PHP array functions it all fell into place quite well.
I understand the code may not be very tidy right now and there may be ways to optimize/improve it, however for the time being it does the job.